# Install ubuntu 14.04 with pxe using local repository

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, repository

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 server from local repository.

I created a local mirror repository with apt-mirror.
The line in `/etc/apt/mirror.list` is :

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

It downloaded about 60G and finished OK.
Install failed with the error :

```
"ubuntu/dist/trusty/restricted/debian-installer/binary-amd64/Packages.gz " ERROR 404 Not Found.
```

I found that directory `ubuntu/dist/trusty/restricted/` contains only `binary-amd64 and i18n directories`

I copied the file `debian-installer/binary-amd64/Packages.gz` from Ubuntu site , but then it failed with a lot of other files missing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support installation from the local repository, the line in `/etc/apt/mirror.list` should be

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `deb-amd64`? Never seen such thing